# how to send post type request without parameter using python requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests, automated-tests

I have method on swagger "Login" that accept this json:

```
{ "login": "string", "password": "string", "supplierId": 0 }
```

I need to send request using request module in Python:

1) First without login attribute

```
{"login": , "password": "user_password", "supplierId": "user_supplierId"}
```

2) With login attribute but without brackets

```
{"login": asd, "password": "user_password", "supplierId": "user_supplierId"}
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the method that accepts json as: { "login": "string", "password": "string", "supplierId": 0 }.

You will probably have to send a string as a value to login variable. You can try passing an empty string `""` if you don't want to send a login value.